sitecore powershell api Get-item
$itemPath = "master:/sitecore/media library/sample/sampleConfig"
$itemPath = Get-Item -Path $itemPath -Language "ja-JP"

I am running a script like the one above.
I get a not exist error even though it definitely exists in the content tree.
What are the possible causes?
Corruption of the INDEX?
$itemPath = “{XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXX}” 
$item = Get-Item -Path “master:” -ID $itemPath -Language “ja-JP” 

As a side note, I was able to retrieve the item by doing the above. Even if the Index is corrupted, can it be retrieved from the ID?

I cannot find of any reason why Get-Item with right item path would not work (except from Security settings, but if it works with ID, that's not your case). Get-Item does not use index. maybe you have a typo in item name, some strange characters? What is the exact path of the item in media library?

The exact path cannot be given due to security concerns, but it is an alphabetic path with no special characters.
The target item was copied from the development CMS to the verification CMS using the package installer.
There is an event that the item copied to the verification CMS cannot be retrieved by Get-Item.
Furthermore, even if you create a child item in the copied item, it cannot be retrieved by Get-Item.
Existing items can be retrieved with Get-Item, so I thought that I could not update anything other than DB data by importing them with package installer.
